# Python ctypes data-type for passing to F90 real(8) data-type

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran, ctypes

I'm using ctypes (Pthyon3.2) to call F90 routines from a shared library on a 64-bit Debian Linux machine. If the F90 routine takes and argument of type,

```
! We're in fortran (F90) 
subroutine MyFunc(FooF90)   
real(8),intent(in) :: FooF90
! do some stuff...
return
```

what should I pass from Python? My guess is,

```
# We're in Python3.2
F90func(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_double(FooPy)))
```

Is this correct? I couldn't easily find a reference for passing fortran arguments of type real(n) from Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look at numpy's `f2py` for wrapping fortran code.  I've found it to be pretty easy to use in general...

Comment: I think this is not necessary and it is an unneeded interconnection, if the subroutine is c-interoperable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`real(8)` is not defined by the standard, so anything can happen (you should get the kind number by `selected_real_kind` or `iso_c_binding` or `iso_fortran_env`). In practice it will be equivalent to `c_double` for most compilers. You are probably using gfortran for which this holds by default.

There might be a problem, if the Python interpreter expects by `value` argument passing by default. Search for `byref()` function in [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: yes, I'm using gfortran - I should have mentioned that. I'm also using byref() but forgot to mention (I'll amend in question). Thanks. Any ctypes/fortran reference material?

Comment: I don't know of any specific material, but I recommend to read about C - Fortran interoperability using iso_c_binding.